# Как вырвать ссылку из $_POST['textarea'];

Tags: php

Прошу помощи, мне через мою контактную форму приходит по 5-8 спам писем в час, во всех случаях присутствует ссылка *http://*

Такой вопрос: как из `$_POST['textarea']` вырвать ссылку, если она там есть? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Добавьте в теги языки и технологии, которые используете, иначе ваш вопрос просто не заметят.

Comment: Проверять строку на наличие ссылки можно  таким образом: `if (preg_match('~https?://\S+~', $_POST['textarea']) { die('Спам!'); }`

Answer (score 0):

От спама неплохо поможет защититься [reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3beta.html).

По Вашему вопросу: 
`$string = "https://vk.com/id1 http://gogo.ru";
echo preg_replace('#[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~\#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~\#?&//=]*)?#si', "[link prohibited]", $string); // output: [link prohibited] [link prohibited].`

Регулярное выражение позаимствовал [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481641/php-regex-match-all-urls).

Comment: Спасибо за старания, reCaptcha invisible уже как пол года установлена, но от неё толку не много.

Comment: попробуйте обычную поставить (v2), всё равно какой-никакой, а профит должен быть.